# Unexpected output on Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I'm using Leonardo and I want to print a message when I type ">" and "<". 
Something like `>my_message<`.

I have the following code but it is not working like I was expecting (nothing happens). How can I fix this or is there a better way to do this?

```
String txtMsg = ""; // a string for incoming text

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}

void loop() {
  // add any incoming characters to the String:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    txtMsg += inChar;

    char StartDelimiter = txtMsg.charAt(0);
    int endDel = txtMsg.length() - 1;
    char EndDelimiter = txtMsg.charAt(endDel);

    if (StartDelimiter == '>' && EndDelimiter == '<') {
      Serial.println(txtMsg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "it is not working like I was expecting." - so what does it actually do?

Comment: Why don't you print what characters you are actually receiving? (As a means of debugging the problem, not a permanent solution)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that your code looking for '>' always looked at character 0 and you were appending to your string, so after getting a first non '>' character you could never get to a condition in which you would print.

```
String txtMsg = ""; // a string for incoming text

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}

void loop() {
    // add any incoming characters to the String:
    int got_start = 0;
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char inChar = Serial.read();
        if (inChar == '>' && !got_start) {
            got_start = 1;
        }
        if (got_start) {
            txtMsg += inChar;
        }   
        if (inChar == '<' && got_start) {
            got_start = 0; 
            Serial.println(txtMsg);
            txtMsg = "";    
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: this is useful but is there any way to do that using `charAt()` function?

Comment: @mafap Do you understand what was wrong with your existing code? You could use `charAt()` after you've appended to the string, but I'm not particularly sure why you would.

Comment: Now I understand. I wanted to use this function because I need to get the value of characters at different positions in a String. I just don't know what's the better way to do that.